# PhoneGap resolveLocalFileSystemURI

Tags: file, cordova, copy, move

I am trying to resolve this filesystem uri shown below:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/9483756B-8D2A-42C5-8CF7-8D76AAA8FF2C/Shift.app/iqedata/5977e2e9239649d5a7e3b8a54719679f/06e2b8896e51472789fcc27575631f94.jpg
```

Can any body tell me how to resolve this uri in PhoneGap and get the FileEntry by using the method showing below?

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(Url, resOnSuccess, resOnError);
```

I have tried to add "file://" or "//" before the uri but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PhoneGap will not let you read files outside of the [APP HASH]/Documents or [APP HASH]/tmp folders. Unless you can find a way to initialize your app with your data in one of these folders, you will have to get your data another way. I have found the below code to work. Basically it downloads the local file into your temp folder and gives you the file entry.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function(fs){
    fs.root.getFile("temp", {create: true, exclusive: false},
      function(entry){
        fileTransfer.download(
                Url, // the filesystem uri you mentioned
                entry.fullPath,
                function(entry) {
                    // do what you want with the entry here
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("error code " + error.code);
                },
                false,
                null
        );
    }, function(){
        alert("file create error");
    });
}, null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This stuff has driven me crazy and your solution works perfectly. And another trick is the uri should start with file:///var/blablabla

Comment: Glad it worked! I usually build my paths starting with location.href, which already has the file:///. That way I don't have to hard code the whole path.

Comment: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI works fine in android for me. But does it would differ for ios. Please let me know.

Comment: @UnchartedSpace its giving me error as "ReferenceError: fileTransfer is not defined" how to resolve this for run your code?

Comment: @SaurabhAndroid You should post your code and problem as a new question. In the question, be sure to give your PhoneGap version along with some sample code and context, and which plugins you have installed.

Comment: @SaurabhAndroid FileTransfer is a different plugin than File... you are probably missing that.