# phonegap/cordova 3.1.0, unable to display contact photo

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to display every contact in the address book, together with their photo.

To do so, I have created a contact in the emulator with a random picture. I have managed to list the contacts without trouble. The first contact contains, as expected, an url to the photo:

`{"id":"1","rawId":"1","displayName":"Test Dude 1","name":{"middleName":"Dude","familyName":"1","formatted":"Test Dude 1","givenName":"Test"},"nickname":null,"phoneNumbers":null,"emails":null,"addresses":null,"ims":null,"organizations":null,"birthday":null,"note":null,"photos":[{"value":"content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1/photo","type":"url","id":"2","pref":false}],"categories":null,"urls":null}`

So, now I'm trying to display the pictures. This is where I'm having trouble. In an attempt to create a minimal example of the error I'm running into, I added an img tag with the URL to the pic of the first contact:

```
<img id="myimg">
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('doing my thing');
        var theurl = 'content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1/photo';
        var element = document.getElementById('myimg');
        element.src = theurl;
        console.log('did my thing');
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

I have not managed to get the picture displayed. This is what the log says:

```
I/Web Console( 3304): doing my thing at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:42
E/webcoreglue( 3304): *** Uncaught exception returned from Java call!
W/System.err( 3304): java.io.IOException: read failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
W/System.err( 3304):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:442)
W/System.err( 3304):    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
W/System.err( 3304):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
W/System.err( 3304):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3304): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: read failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
W/System.err( 3304):    at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3304):    at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:123)
W/System.err( 3304):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:149)
W/System.err( 3304):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:432)
W/System.err( 3304):    ... 3 more
I/Web Console( 3304): did my thing at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:54
```

I'm using cordova 3.1.0 and an emulated Android device with platform 4.2.2 and API level 17. I believe I have the relevant permissions set (`READ_CONTACTS`, `WRITE_CONTACTS`, added `GET_ACCOUNTS`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in case they would help).

What am I doing wrong? How can I further diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to be replying to my own question after being able to resolve the issue.

Apparently you can't directly access the URL of the photo directly. But you can transfer it to temp storage and link to that. The method to do so is described in the answer to this question:

[PhoneGap resolveLocalFileSystemURI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065494/phonegap-resolvelocalfilesystemuri)