# Contact image from Phonegap not displayed

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I saw several posts related to this like [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459002/phonegap-cordova-3-1-0-unable-to-display-contact-photo) but not working for me . I tried like below

**First method:**

Directly set image source from contact image value

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("cimg");
myImg.src = contacts[i].photos[0].value;
```

this one not display the image in img tag.

**Second Method:**

Pass the contact image value to the fileDownload option

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function(fs){
                        fs.root.getFile("temp.jpg", {create: true, exclusive: false},
                          function(entry){
                            //alert(entry.toURL());
                            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                            fileTransfer.download(
                                    contacts[i].photos[0].value, // the filesystem uri you mentioned
                                    entry.fullPath,
                                    function(entry) {
                                        // do what you want with the entry here
                                        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                                        var src = entry.fullPath; 
                                        //$("").append('<img src="'+src+'" >');
                                    },
                                    function(error) {
                                        alert("error source " + error.source);
                                        console.log("error target " + error.target);
                                        console.log("error code " + error.code);
                                        console.log(error);
                                    },
                                    false,
                                    null
                            );
                        }, function(e){
                            console.log("file create error",e);
                        });
                    }, null);
```

This one shows error like `07-28 07:37:56.468: E/FileTransfer(20986): {"target":"file:\/\/\/mnt\/sdcard\/Android\/data\/io.cordova.hellocordova\/cache\/temp.jpg","http_status":0,"code":3,"source":"content:\/\/com.android.contacts\/contacts\/2\/photo","exception":"read failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)"}
07-28 07:37:56.468: E/FileTransfer(20986): java.io.IOException: read failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)`

Edit :

my phonegap **contact[i].photo[0].value** return like **"content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1/photo"**

how to resolve this one. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

please check what android version you are testing. Because there have a lot changes structures android 2.0  ->  2.2.. Can you try on android above 4.0 + ?