# resolve content:// from email attachment on android with javascript or plugin

Tags: email, cordova, phonegap-plugins, custom-component

I built the app with Cordova/Phonegap 3.x - my app is able to send custom type file (actually it's text file but with my custom .jof extension) as attachment via device email client.

Unfortunately, when I try to open attached .jof using Webintent:
https://github.com/InQBarna/WebIntent.git plugin via CDV.WEBINTENT.getUri() it gives me URI

content://downloads/all_downloads/296

I was expecting there will be a path to the file:// but it looks like Android make it more sophisticated and not easy. So my question is what is the simplest way to open 'content://' resource not writing in JAVA using cordova API only? Are there any plugins for this?

Comment: I resolved this problem downloading URI (content://) with Cordova API - **FileTransfer** to temporary file located inside app sandbox and then having file entry opened such file with Cordova **FileReader**.

Comment: I have followed the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065494/phonegap-resolvelocalfilesystemuri - and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later but I have faced this problem recently and maybe my solution works for anyone. I have found the following plugin:
[cordova-plugin-filepath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filepath)

It will transform the url with format 'content://...' to a valid file path url, the only "downside" is that it doesn't append 'file://' to the begining of the file path (just append it by yourself).

Example of how I use it in my cordova app:

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
  window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imageURI, function(result) {
    // onSuccess code
    imageURI = 'file://' + result;
    . . .
  }, function (error) {
    // onError code here
  }
}
```