# Can't remove audio file on with phonegap app in iOS

Tags: cordova, audio, media, delete-file

I have a phonegap app that is recording an audio file and then uploading it to a server. After the upload I am trying to remove the file. It works fine on Android but I cannot find the path that I can remove it on iOS with. The code I am using to remove it is:

```
    removeAudioFile = function() {
    if ($scope.audioFname != '') {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI($scope.audioFname, onSuccessDel, onErrorDel);
    }
    function onSuccessDel(fileEntry) {
        console.log(fileEntry.name);
        $scope.audioFname = '';
        $interval(function () {
            fileEntry.remove(function() {console.log('File Removed');}, function() {console.log('File Remove failed');});
        }, 3000, 1);
    }

    function onErrorDel(error) {
        $scope.audioFname = '';
        showMessage('We had a problem removing your audio file, '+ error.code);
    }

}
```

I get an error every time. I create the media with the code below.
I play back the sound file successfully also.

```
var myFname = new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
$scope.mediaRec = new Media(myFname, function () { ...
```

I have tried prepending:
file:///
/
file:///mnt/sdcard/
file:///sdcard

Any help on this?

Comment: maybe related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065494/phonegap-resolvelocalfilesystemuri

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, I saw that post. One of the problems is that the fs.root.getFile() method never calls the success or the fail call back for iOS, but works find on Android. So I can't use that approach.